# Второе тире после однородных членов в простом предложении перед союзом

Tags: тире

В ходе исследования использовались следующие методы: общенаучные - идеализации, формализации, метод восхождения от абстрактного к конкретному, абстрагирования, индукции и дедукции - и  специальные экономические, финансовые.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вариант вполне корректный: однородные члены как пояснение.

Возможен такой вариант:

В ходе исследования использовались следующие методы: общенаучные - идеализации, формализации, метод восхождения от абстрактного к конкретному, абстрагирования, индукции и дедукции  и специальные - экономические, финансовые. Здесь чётко просматривается структура отношений рядов однородных членов.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаемый вариант:

В ходе исследования использовались  как общенаучные методы: идеализация, формализация, восхождение от абстрактного к конкретному, абстрагирование, индукция и дедукция, так и  специальные: экономические, финансовые.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) В принципе однородный ряд перед союзом "И" можно обособить двумя тире, но не в этом предложении, где получится три тире.

2) Не ставить второе тире тоже не очень хорошо, так как  обособленная конструкция больше похожа на вставку, а там два тире обязательны.

Answer (score 0):

В ходе исследования использовались и общенаучные методы: идеализация, формализация, метод восхождения от абстрактного к конкретному, абстрагирование, индукция, дедукция, - и специальные экономические, финансовые.